# In bash, how do I get a file name without the final extension with parameter substitution?

Tags: bash

I'm iterating over all the `*.info` files in a directory, and checking to see if there is a corresponding `*.gz` file (and removing the `.info` file if there isn't).  But to do this, I need to strip the `.info` off of `$file`.  I've fiddled around with parameter substitution in `bash` but nothing seems to work.  I can get the extension easily enough (as the code below does) but not everything *but* the extension.  I tried various things I expected might work; none did.

```
for file in *.info; do
  gz_file="${file:(-4)}"                        # wrong... what is right?
  # gz_file=`echo "$file" | sed -e 's/.info//'` # easy alternative I'm trying to avoid
  if [[ ! -f "${gz_file}" ]]; then
    rm "${file}"
  fi
done
```

I realize this can easily be done with `sed`, as shown in the commented-out line, but I'd like to do it with the variable manipulation capabilities built into bash, if that's possible, because I think it'll be handy to have figured out how to make it work that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try `${file%.*}` ?
This should remove the extension.

Comment: No, but I tried sputnick's answer, and it worked.  Wouldn't `${file%.*}` create a problem for files with more than one `.` character?  (Mine happen to be like that.)

Comment: `${file%.*}` removes only after the last `.` occurrence. `${file%%.*}` removes all after the first `.`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ x=/foo/bar.info
$ echo ${x%.info}
/foo/bar
$
```